# How to use Bootstrap 4 (3) Mixins

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, mixins, bootstrap-4

How to use Bootstrap mixins. I use Bootstrap 4 in combination with CSS Modules, SCSS. For example this is a bootstrap mixins for input-size.

```
@mixin input-size($parent, $input-height, $padding-y, $padding-x, $font-size, $line-height, $border-radius) {
  #{$parent} {
    height: $input-height;
    padding: $padding-y $padding-x;
    font-size: $font-size;
    line-height: $line-height;
    @include border-radius($border-radius);
  }

  select#{$parent} {
    height: $input-height;
    line-height: $input-height;
  }

  textarea#{$parent},
  select[multiple]#{$parent} {
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

If I want to use it how would I do it?

**First.jsx**

```
<form>
  <div className={`form-group ${styles.formula}`}>
    <label htmlFor='exampleInputEmail1'>Email address</label>
    <input type='email' className='form-control' id='exampleInputEmail1' aria-describedby='emailHelp' placeholder='Enter email' />
    <small id='emailHelp' className='form-text text-muted'>We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
```

I am using it like this. The customBtn works good so I know it is not a settings problem. Input element is not?
**styles.scss**

```
.customBtn {
  @include button-variant(white, purple, black)
}
.formula {
  @include input-size('.form-control', 70px, 12px, 12px, 32px, 5em, 0)
}
```

***Update**
Fixed it.
It seems there was a problem with CSS Modules and Bootstrap class naming combination. I managed to resolve it like this.

**First.jsx**

```
<form>
  <div className={`form-group ${styles.formula}`}>
    <label htmlFor='exampleInputEmail1'>Email address</label>
    <input type='email' className={`form-control ${styles.formControl}`} id='exampleInputEmail1' aria-describedby='emailHelp' placeholder='Enter email' />
    <small id='emailHelp' className='form-text text-muted'>We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
   </div>
```

**styles.scss**

```
.customBtn {
  @include button-variant(white, purple, black)
}
.formula {
  @include input-size('.formControl', 70px, 12px, 12px, 32px, 5em, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you're passing in the correct param values to the mixin. For example,

```
@import "bootstrap";
.my-custom-input {  
  @include input-size('.form-control', 70px, 12px, 12px, 32px, 5em, 0)
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/zc544u3kYN

**Update** the `input-size` mixin has been removed in Bootstrap 4 Beta.

Comment: I must be missing something obvious. It's still not working. I updated the question, can you please take a look at it.

Comment: `.formula` should be applied to the parent of the `.form-control`.. for example the `form group`

Comment: Tried changing it around(updated the First.jsx in question) but still no luck.

Comment: There's nothing else to try. As you can see the Codeply works, so the .formula class must not be properly getting applied to the HTML.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to fix it. See the solution in question. Thanks for putting me on right path. I have just one more question. I am using CSS Modules, Mixins and Bootstrap to style every component on its own. I would like to use _custom.scss file that comes with bootstrap to style everything globaly. If I change styles in _custom.scss it works but if for example I delete node_modules, everything is gone. Is there a way to extract/use _custom.scss outside the node_modules?